# How to give custom style to dojo ValidationTextBox?

Tags: css, dojo

How to give custom style to dojo ValidationTextBox?

We need to override the default css applied to dojo ValidationTextBox. Currently when the field is required, it shows some yellow background and a exclamation mark around the textbox.

See below

[image]

Or is it possible to remove the yellow background and the exclamation mark and just keep the tooltip error message?

Comment: Include your `stylesheet` with dojo styles override after dojo `stylesheet`.

Answer (score 2):

```
.tundra .dijitSelectError .dijitButtonContents, 
.tundra .dijitTextBoxError, 
.tundra .dijitTextBoxError .dijitButtonNode {
    border-color: #d46464;
}

.tundra .dijitError {
    background-color: #d46464;
}

.tundra .dijitValidationTextBoxError .dijitValidationIcon {    
    background: url('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=5') no-repeat -55px -66px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/Yytzj/